# How to calculate distance between iPhone device and User without using ARKit, if we already know height of User?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mobile

I am developing an App to calculate the distance between an iPhone device and its user by using the front camera without ARKit. I already know the height of the user, just want to know how to calculate distance between device and user.

I had already tried various formulas given on StackOverFlow and other websites but get stuck with "Sensor size/height" as we are not getting this in EXIF from iPhone. If I can find this also, I can try using this formula:

[image]

How can I retrieve the sensor height?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?